# How to test a function that downloads a stream of HLS into one file?

Tags: go, http, testing

I am trying to write a test function for a function that downloads a stream of hls into one `.mp3` file
// the download function

```
func DownloadM3u8(filepath string, dlbar *bar.ProgressBar, segments []string) error {

    file, _ := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    // the go routine now
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, segment := range segments {
        wg.Add(1)
        downloadSeg(&wg, segment, file, dlbar)
    }

    return nil
}


func downloadSeg(wg *sync.WaitGroup, segmentURI string, file *os.File, dlbar *bar.ProgressBar) {
    defer wg.Done()
    resp, err := http.Get(segmentURI)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // append to the file
    if dlbar == nil {
        _, err = io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(file), resp.Body)
    } else {
        _, err = io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(file, dlbar), resp.Body)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

}
```

The passed segments are list of URIs like this sample :

```
[
https://url-adc.com/s/933030/30032, 
https://url-adc.com/s/933030/303220,
https://url-adc.com/s/933030/34230,
https://url-adc.com/s/933030/35290,
]
```

The test function basically mimic the download, as I have actual downloaded file : `Test[medium].mp3`, I am trying to split/splice that file into `[]byte` and assign each byte range to some `url`, then with the help of `httptest` package I return the corresponding `[]byte`.

```
func TestDownloadM3u8(t *testing.T) {

    path := "../../testdata/"
    track := readTestFile("Test[medium].mp3") // []byte

    fileName := "some filename that exists" // the filename of the tmp file.mp3 that is expected to be downloaded.
    path = filepath.Join(path, fileName)
       // the segments from the actual file, valid file
    segments := extractSegments(fileResp, track)

    // modifiying the seg urls to mimic the actual urls
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // write bytes based on the url
        n, _ := strconv.Atoi(req.URL.String()[1:])
        if bs, ok := segments[n]; ok {
            res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            res.Write(bs)
        }
    }))

    defer testServer.Close()

    segmentURIs := make([]string, 0)
    for k := range segments {
        segmentURIs = append(segmentURIs, testServer.URL+"/"+strconv.Itoa(k))
    }
    soundcloud.DownloadM3u8(path, nil, segmentURIs)

    // read the downloaded file
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error happened while reading the track, error : %s", err)
    }
    // TODO: not the best method, as it loads all the file in memeory, but for this test it's ok since the size isn't that big + I have RAM
    if !bytes.Equal(file, track) {
        t.Errorf("Expected the 2 files to be the same")
    }
    // remove the file
    // os.Remove(path)
}
```

I tried to extract the segments by splitting the file into `[]byte` with the same length as the segments length that I get from reading the `playlist.m3u8` file (that file contains segment.URIs, it's returned by other function).

```
func extractSegments(fileP []byte, testfile []byte) map[int][]byte {
    segments := make(map[int][]byte, 0)
    reader := bytes.NewReader(fileP)

    pl, listType, err := m3u8.DecodeFrom(reader, true)

    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch listType {
    case m3u8.MEDIA:
        mediapl := pl.(*m3u8.MediaPlaylist)
        for i, segment := range mediapl.Segments {
            if segment == nil {
                continue
            }
                     // here I want to get portion of the testfile
            segments[i] = ...
        }
    }

    return segments
}
```

I tried to write a function that splits the `testfile` into `[][]bytes` but the test fails as the 2 files aren't identical, I compared the 2 file, but they aren't the same.

```
    var segmentSize int
    numSegments := len(segments)

    fileSize := len(testfile)
    segmentSize = fileSize / numSegments

    for i := 0; i < numSegments-1; i++ {
        start := i * segmentSize
        end := (i + 1) * segmentSize
        segments[i] = testfile[start:end]
    }

    // handle the last segment
    start := (numSegments - 1) * segmentSize
    end := fileSize
    if fileSize%numSegments == 0 {
        end = (numSegments-1)*segmentSize + segmentSize
    }
    segments[int(numSegments-1)] = testfile[start:end]
```

Comment: Hello, instead of trying to split the reassembled file, why not downloading as testdata the individual files and then serve them from the test server? Seems simpler and closer to what the real server does :-)